# How to get datetime from a pandas dataframe by row index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How to get the date from this following dataframe by row index? I am looking for a function something like:

```
get_datetime(dataframe, row_index = 1)
```

which will return the datetime as `2022-01-11`

I have read the [Time series / date functionality of Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html), however, did not see anything useful there.

```
             open   high    low  close    volume  dividends  stock splits
Date                                                                     
2022-01-06  21.99  22.22  21.59  22.18   1956300          0             0
2022-01-11  22.32  22.93  22.23  22.92   1885700          0             0
2022-01-21  22.40  22.55  22.02  22.13   2265500          0             0
2022-01-26  22.28  22.72  21.79  22.05   2247600          0             0
2022-01-31  22.02  22.92  21.72  22.86   2955500          0             0
2022-02-10  24.73  25.51  24.59  25.29   4069300          0             0
2022-02-15  24.85  25.57  24.56  25.47   5661100          0             0
2022-02-25  24.59  25.07  24.46  24.67   3722400          0             0
2022-03-02  23.20  23.95  23.15  23.82   3268100          0             0
2022-03-07  21.54  21.60  19.51  19.59  10102600          0             0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the index with `df.index`

```py
df.index[1]
```

If your index is datetime, you can use [`DatetimeIndex.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html) to get the `datetime.date` objects

```py
df.index.date[1]
```

Or with [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) to get string format

```py
df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')[1]
# use `str` for convenience if the format is %Y-%m-%d
str(df.index.date[1])
```

Comment: The command works, however, the result returns as `Timestamp('2022-01-11 00:00:00')`. Should I convert it into string and trim as required to get `'2022-01-11`?

Comment: @Sedmaister Result is `Timestamp` is because your index is datetime, it depends on you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this to get it just as the date without the timestamp:

```
df.index[0].date()
```

prints: `2022-01-06`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.index` to reference the row index. It's a RangeIndex that is similar to a list, try this and see what happens:

```
list(df.index)
```

You should see a list of row index. So to refer to any element in the list, use the `list[index]` format, for example

```
df.index[0]
df.index[-1]
```